# Accelerated Database Recovery SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, accelerated-database-recovery

I have ADR enabled on my production database running on SQL Server 2019. In the SQL Server logs , it shows the messages:

> [VersionCleaner][DbId:6][sweepOfSelectivePages]: Cleanup of sidelist
> aborted due to timeout 0 minutes. 130686 number of pages have been
> processed

I did not get information about these messages in any blogs. can you help me understand the messages?

Comment: Welcome to [dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) 
 What research have you done so far? [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1501497)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer but I'd start by trying to understand what might be causing the cleanup of the persistent version store and possibly try running the PVS cleanup manually.

There's lots of advice here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-troubleshoot?view=sql-server-ver15